# How can we guarantee onAttach will always work (Fragment)?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Is there any way to guarentee onAttach will work?

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

If I call getActivity() later down in the fragment, should I be concerned and always do:

```
if(getActivity()!=null)
```

And what should I do if it is null?

The order of the fragment flow is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I call getActivity() later down in the fragment, should I be concerned and always do: if(getActivity()!=null)

That would depend upon the nature of "later down in the fragment". While on the main application thread, in between calls to `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`, `getActivity()` should return a non-`null` value. However:

- If your fragment is managing an `AsyncTask` or other background thread, calls on that thread could be going on while attaching/detaching is occurring (e.g., configuration change), and therefore such background threads should not be trying to reference the activity
- If you have methods that you're not sure are called between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`, practice defensive programming and validate that the `Activity` that you get back from `getActivity()` is not `null`

> And what should I do if it is null?

Fail gracefully. Beyond that, we have no way of advising you, as we have no idea what you are trying to do with the activity.